# How to add/remove class to parent div according to input radio selection using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, input, radio-button

the below code shows 4 radio buttons that are hidden by default using the display:none property in CSS. However, I select them using the "label" tag. I also have a div wrapping everything.

I want to know how can I add/remove a class to this "div" tag if the contained radio box is selected.

So if I select a radio, the parent div will get a class, and if another radio is selected, the class is removed from this div and added to the parent div of the radio selected.

```
<div class="plan">
   <h3 class="division-one">Division One<span>€2</span></h3>
   <div><label for="23">1 month</label><input type="radio" name="membershipPlanSID" value="23" id="23" /></div>
   <div><label for="24">3 months</label><input type="radio" name="membershipPlanSID" value="24" id="24" /></div>
   <div><label for="25">6 months</label><input type="radio" name="membershipPlanSID" value="25" id="25" /></div>
   <div><label for="26">12 months</label><input type="radio" name="membershipPlanSID" value="26" id="26" /></div>
   <input type="hidden" name="returnBackUri" value="{$returnBackUri}" />
   <input class="signup" type="submit" value="[[Sign Up:raw]]" />
</div>
```

I tried something like this, but with no success:

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('label-selected');
} else {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('label-selected');
}
});
```

Doing this, the class is never removed, despite the "else".

Thanks all in advance,
Arky

EDIT: Thanks a lot guys for the very fast answers! Amazing community here :)

Comment: I was playing around with a similar concept recently: http://jsfiddle.net/ZK4th/1/

Comment: That's very much what I was trying to achieve. The problem is that I suck at programming :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Remember that a `radio` input element gets "unchecked" only when one of its counterparts is clicked. Unlike a `checkbox` input element, clicking a second time on a `radio` input does not clear its value.

In your example, on the first click you are successfully adding the class to the parent `div` since the `radio` input is indeed `:checked`, but on the second click on the *same* `radio` input, that element remains `:checked` and therefore the parent's class is not removed.

**Solution**

Onclick of a `radio` input element, remove the class from all `div` elements *except* the immediate parent.

For example:

```
 $('.plan :radio').on('click', function() {
     var parent_div = $(this).parent().addClass('label-selected');
     $('.plan').find('div').not(parent_div).removeClass('label-selected');
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly as all the other solutions. But this one gets the cake due the thorough explanation. Thanks again.

Comment: This fails on programatic change:  `$('.plan :radio:checked').prop('checked',false);`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss True. This also fails changes in the DOM, like `$(':radio').wrap('span')`. For the most generalized approach see undefined's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input:radio').click(function () {
    $('div.plan div').removeClass('label-selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('label-selected');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cXLv6/)**

Answer (score 1):

The input that triggers the event is the checked one, so there is no need to use `if` statement. Add the class to the parent `div` element and remove it from it's `div` siblings.

```
$(function(){
    $('.plan input[type=radio]').change(function() {
       $(this).closest('div')
              .addClass('label-selected')
              .siblings('div')
              .removeClass('label-selected');              
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GXdyP/

Answer (score 0):

If this were checkboxes, it would work, but since it only affects the one that was just clicked, it won't remove the class from the other boxes. Try this:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        $('div.plan div').removeClass('label-selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('label-selected');
});
```

This will remove the class from all the other elements before adding it to the one you want.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6MYtW/)